# How to perform in single query

Tags: java, jdo

I have two class Subscriber and subscription. A subscription class have field named status having values (Active, Pending, Completed, Deactivated).
A subscriber can have multiple subscription having different status values.

**What I have to do**

I have to show subscription only 6 weeks after deactivation and completion means after 6 week I have to delete them and also delete those subscriber who doesn't have any active and pending subscription.

*Pre-condition:*
Whenever a subscriber registered, a subscription with 'pending' status is created.

**What I have performed**

```
public class Subscriber {
    List<Subscription> subscriptionList;
}  

public class Subscription {
    String status;
    Date modifiedDate;
}

public class PerformOperation {

    public static void main() {
        DateTime currDate = new DateTime();
        DateTime date = currDate.minusDays(42);
        Query query = pm.newQuery(Subscription.class); /*where pm is PersistentManager*/
        query.setFilter("(status == 'Completed' && status == 'Deactivated') && modifiedDate <= date");
        query.declareParameter("java.util.Date date");
        query.deleteAllPersistent(new Date(date.toMillis()));

        Query query1 = pm.newQuery(Subscriber.class);
        query1.setFilter("subscriptionList.isEmpty()");
        query1.deleteAllPersistent();

    }
}
```

Is there any better way to do it using jdo?

Comment: please share your table designs, I think you can write two simple SQL queries and achieve your objective

Comment: Subscriber ans subscription mentioned in above question is database table

Comment: want to see the columns of the two tables

Comment: I have to perform operation using jdo. We have not to use raw sql query.

Comment: You want to delete Subscriber AND Subscription in one query?! Impossible. Each deletePersistentAll is for a candidate type.

Comment: @NeilStockton what i have done is best way to perform above operation.

Comment: Is that a question? I don't see classes so can't comment on the majority of this. I can say that "subscriptionList.isEmpty" is invalid ... "isEmpty" is a method so needs "()" ... assuming that "subscriptionList" is a Collection field of course

Comment: Yes i have used "subscriptionList.isEmpty()" in actual implementation.